# REST API, nested routes without providing identifiers at every nested level

Tags: rest, api, api-design

Obviously a RESTful API could contain base routes such as:

```
api/competitions
api/competitions/{id}
api/teams
api/teams/{id}
api/players
api/players/{id}
```

And nested routes such as:

```
api/competitions/{id}/teams
api/competitions/{id}/teams/{id}/players
api/teams/{id}/players
...
```

But what about the following example (*Route A*):

```
api/competitions/{id}/teams/players
```

So all players, for all teams that are in a certain competition?

**Q1:** Would this contravene REST design?

**Q2:** Presumably it does, but is there any documentation that explicitly states this? I have done some research and cannot find anything that rules it out as the examples are all very simplistic.

You could implement (*Route B*):

```
api/competitions/{id}/players
```

instead, and then underneath the logic would ensure that the players are not ALL players (as in `api/players`) but take into account team and therefore competition - so that players that are without a team are excluded.

However, moving away from this simple example to a more abstract model, there might be scenarios where *Route B* might be more confusing to an API consumer than *Route A*.

**Q3:** Would there ever be a justification for implementing a nested route (like *Route A*) without all identifiers at every level?

Answer (score 3):

1. No. REST doesn't care about how your organize your resources, only that individual resources are identified by URLs and that resources are discoverable from other resources. If `api/competitions/{id}/teams/players` makes sense for your application then use it, as long as users can find a link to it.
2. Roy Fielding's dissertation on [Representational State Transfer](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm), specifically sections [5.2.1.1 Resources and Resource Identifiers](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) and [6.2 REST Applied to URI](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2). Also look into HATEOAS (Hypertext as the Engine of Application State).
3. Yes, if it is both understood by and convenient for users of your application.

REST is a high-level architectural concept. It's not concerned with how you nest your identifiers. That's up to you and your application requirements. Do what makes sense and be obvious about it.